# Recharts: I am getting a tooltip when i hover on header elements, how to disable it?

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am getting some sort of a tooltip when i use Recharts on my page, everytime i hover over text elements. How can i disable this? I looked through the Recharts docs and tried to find others with the same issue.

[Example on the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehUMJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.